# Recover from an vector out of reach error

Tags: c++, exception, vector

is it possible to recover from vector "out of reach" error in C++?

Like this function:

```
vector<int> numbers;

bool isAccessable(int i)
{
   try
   {
  numbers[i];
   catch (...)
    {
    return false;
    }

return true;
}
```

it's possible in C#, but c++?

Comment: Usign exceptions for flow control is a bad idea. Why don't you just check the range before accessing an element: `if (i >= 0 && i < numbers.size()) { ... }` Isn't this much clearer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to check whether the index is in range, then simply:

```
return i < numbers.size();
```

(You should also either compare with zero, or change the index to an unsigned type; `size_t` is the type usually used for array indexes.)

If you want to try to access the value, and throw an exception if the index is out of range, then use `at` rather than `[]`:

```
try {
    do_something_with(numbers.at(i));
    return true;
} catch (std::out_of_range const &) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what if function already uses [] . it came with a static library and i dont have access to source code :( . vector is a protected member. is it still possible?

Comment: @mikbak: Unfortunately not. `[]` has undefined behaviour if the index is out of range, unless you use an implementation of `vector` that adds extra error checking.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ there is no range check for operator[], but there is for vector::at().

Try

```
numbers.at(i);
```

instead.

Comment: operator[] is allowed to perform a range-check, but it is not required. at() requires a range-check.

Comment: Ok, in C++ there is *most often* no range check for `operator[]`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::vector::at()` member function. It throws an `out_of_range` exception.